# A new and (almost) effective way to update routes and allow external access

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools, openshift-3, openshift-enterprise

This is a procedure I tried to use to update all the routes of an already installed cluster to allow external access to it.

The procedure below seems very viable to me, but we have been having some problems so I would like your help to solve this big problem that has been consuming me for days... =|

---

**PROCEDURES:**

I found all ***namespaces*** that have *routes*...

```
[root@okd4-services okd_bare_metal]# oc get routes --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE                  NAME                HOST/PORT                                                   PATH   SERVICES            PORT    TERMINATION            WILDCARD
openshift-authentication   oauth-openshift     oauth-openshift.apps.mbr.okd.local                                 oauth-openshift     6443    passthrough/Redirect   None
openshift-console          console             console-openshift-console.apps.mbr.okd.local                       console             https   reencrypt/Redirect     None
openshift-console          downloads           downloads-openshift-console.apps.mbr.okd.local                     downloads           http    edge/Redirect          None
openshift-ingress-canary   canary              canary-openshift-ingress-canary.apps.mbr.okd.local                 ingress-canary      8080    edge/Redirect          None
openshift-monitoring       alertmanager-main   alertmanager-main-openshift-monitoring.apps.mbr.okd.local          alertmanager-main   web     reencrypt/Redirect     None
openshift-monitoring       grafana             grafana-openshift-monitoring.apps.mbr.okd.local                    grafana             https   reencrypt/Redirect     None
openshift-monitoring       prometheus-k8s      prometheus-k8s-openshift-monitoring.apps.mbr.okd.local             prometheus-k8s      web     reencrypt/Redirect     None
openshift-monitoring       thanos-querier      thanos-querier-openshift-monitoring.apps.mbr.okd.local             thanos-querier      web     reencrypt/Redirect     None
```

I found all the resources related to each *namespace* and took note of the *route* configuration paths...

```
[root@okd4-services okd_bare_metal]# oc -n openshift-authentication get all
[...]
NAME                                       HOST/PORT                            PATH   SERVICES          PORT   TERMINATION            WILDCARD
route.route.openshift.io/oauth-openshift   oauth-openshift.apps.mbr.okd.local          oauth-openshift   6443   passthrough/Redirect   None
```

```
[root@okd4-services okd_bare_metal]# oc -n openshift-console get all
[...]
NAME                                 HOST/PORT                                        PATH   SERVICES    PORT    TERMINATION          WILDCARD
route.route.openshift.io/console     console-openshift-console.apps.mbr.okd.local            console     https   reencrypt/Redirect   None
route.route.openshift.io/downloads   downloads-openshift-console.apps.mbr.okd.local          downloads   http    edge/Redirect        None
```

```
[root@okd4-services okd_bare_metal]# oc -n openshift-ingress-canary get all
[...]
NAME                              HOST/PORT                                            PATH   SERVICES         PORT   TERMINATION     WILDCARD
route.route.openshift.io/canary   canary-openshift-ingress-canary.apps.mbr.okd.local          ingress-canary   8080   edge/Redirect   None
```

```
[root@okd4-services okd_bare_metal]# oc -n openshift-monitoring get all
[...]
NAME                                         HOST/PORT                                                   PATH   SERVICES            PORT    TERMINATION          WILDCARD
route.route.openshift.io/alertmanager-main   alertmanager-main-openshift-monitoring.apps.mbr.okd.local          alertmanager-main   web     reencrypt/Redirect   None
route.route.openshift.io/grafana             grafana-openshift-monitoring.apps.mbr.okd.local                    grafana             https   reencrypt/Redirect   None
route.route.openshift.io/prometheus-k8s      prometheus-k8s-openshift-monitoring.apps.mbr.okd.local             prometheus-k8s      web     reencrypt/Redirect   None
route.route.openshift.io/thanos-querier      thanos-querier-openshift-monitoring.apps.mbr.okd.local             thanos-querier      web     reencrypt/Redirect   None
```

In each route I updated the *host* property to a new domain...

```
oc edit -n openshift-console route.route.openshift.io/console
oc edit -n openshift-console route.route.openshift.io/downloads
oc edit -n openshift-ingress-canary route.route.openshift.io/canary
oc edit -n openshift-monitoring route.route.openshift.io/alertmanager-main
oc edit -n openshift-monitoring route.route.openshift.io/grafana
oc edit -n openshift-monitoring route.route.openshift.io/prometheus-k8s
oc edit -n openshift-monitoring route.route.openshift.io/thanos-querier
```

In other words, I modified something like this...

```
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
kind: Route
metadata:
[...]
spec:
  host: route-name.apps.mbr.okd.local
[...]
status:
[...]
    host: route-name.apps.mbr.okd.local
[...]
```

... to something like this...

```
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
kind: Route
metadata:
[...]
spec:
  host: route-name.apps.mbr.mydomain.net
[...]
status:
[...]
    host: route-name.apps.mbr.mydomain.net
[...]
```

In the case of the *route* `route.route.openshift.io/oauth-openshift` I needed to modify the *ingress*...

```
oc edit ingress.config.openshift.io
```

... modifing the *domain* property from something like this...

```
apiVersion: config.openshift.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
[...]
spec:
  domain: apps.mbr.okd.local
[...]
```

... to something like this...

```
apiVersion: config.openshift.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
[...]
spec:
  domain: apps.mbr.mydomain.net
[...]
```

After doing the above procedures all my routes were updated to the new domain...

```
[root@okd4-services okd_bare_metal]# oc get routes --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE                  NAME                HOST/PORT                                                     PATH   SERVICES            PORT    TERMINATION            WILDCARD
openshift-authentication   oauth-openshift     oauth-openshift.apps.mbr.mydomain.net                                 oauth-openshift     6443    passthrough/Redirect   None
openshift-console          console             console-openshift-console.apps.mbr.mydomain.net                       console             https   reencrypt/Redirect     None
openshift-console          downloads           downloads-openshift-console.apps.mbr.mydomain.net                     downloads           http    edge/Redirect          None
openshift-ingress-canary   canary              canary-openshift-ingress-canary.apps.mbr.mydomain.net                 ingress-canary      8080    edge/Redirect          None
openshift-monitoring       alertmanager-main   alertmanager-main-openshift-monitoring.apps.mbr.mydomain.net          alertmanager-main   web     reencrypt/Redirect     None
openshift-monitoring       grafana             grafana-openshift-monitoring.apps.mbr.mydomain.net                    grafana             https   reencrypt/Redirect     None
openshift-monitoring       prometheus-k8s      prometheus-k8s-openshift-monitoring.apps.mbr.mydomain.net             prometheus-k8s      web     reencrypt/Redirect     None
openshift-monitoring       thanos-querier      thanos-querier-openshift-monitoring.apps.mbr.mydomain.net             thanos-querier      web     reencrypt/Redirect     None
```

---

**PROBLEMS:**

However the following new problems arose...

I can access the new ***Web Console*** route...

`https://console-openshift-console.apps.mbr.mydomain.net/`

... and it redirects to the route below (old domain)...

`https://oauth-openshift.apps.mbr.okd.local/oauth/authorize?client_id=console&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fconsole-openshift-console.apps.mbr.mydomain.net%2Fauth%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=user%3Afull&state=3ba1134a`

[image: Screenshot_20210703_012238]

... but we can use the new route...

`https://oauth-openshift.apps.mbr.mydomain.net/oauth/authorize?client_id=console&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fconsole-openshift-console.apps.mbr.mydomain.net%2Fauth%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=user%3Afull&state=3ba1134a`

...so great works...

[image: Screenshot_20210703_011758]

... I enter the login, password, click on *Log in* and I'm redirected to this URL...

`https://console-openshift-console.apps.mbr.mydomain.net/error?error=invalid_code&error_type=auth`

... which in turn redirects to this (old domain)...

`https://oauth-openshift.apps.mbr.okd.local/oauth/authorize?client_id=console&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fconsole-openshift-console.apps.mbr.mydomain.net%2Fauth%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=user%3Afull&state=da4a1dd0`

[image: Screenshot_20210703_012317]

---

**CONCLUSION:**

Even though we successfully updated the routes as exposed, we started to have **problems with the login** and the **URLs of the *Web Console* that are not updated** to the new domain.

---

---

**QUESTION:**

Does anyone have any idea how we can solve the mentioned problems?

---

**IMPORTANT:**
I - We've already tried this procedure [Customizing the web console URL](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/web_console/customizing-the-web-console.html#customizing-the-web-console-url_customizing-web-console) , but it doesn't update all routes and does not update URLs in the *Web Console* and also has the same login issues above;
II - I also tried this procedure [Creating a route through an Ingress object](https://docs.okd.io/latest/networking/routes/route-configuration.html#nw-ingress-creating-a-route-via-an-ingress_route-configuration) , but equally it doesn't seem to me something that will solve the problems pointed out.

Comment: If there is any problem with this question. We ask for elegance and kindness to inform you what it is. Thanks! =D

Comment: I created a new way to allow external access by domain different from the internal domain ("base domain") of OpenShift (OKD). There is only one small detail to make it 100%. I think this may be interesting for you, so please take a look at this link... https://github.com/openshift/okd/discussions/739 . =D

Comment: Naturally if I solve the problem I will bring the answer to this forum as well!

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/networking/ingress-operator.html#nw-installation-ingress-config-asset_configuring-ingress) is pretty clear: you cannot currently update the `domain` value of the ingress controller:

```
The domain value must be unique among all Ingress Controllers and cannot be updated.
```

You can try to change your clusterConfig and adjust the domain, afterward try to delete and recreate the ingressController. There may be dragons

Comment: But, it would be great if we could. That's what I was trying to do. 